# How to list complex Spanish names in Last + First order in an index?

Tags: language, naming, indexing

I am writing a book that covers Latin American history, but is written in English.

There are many Spanish names. Here I've listed some examples, and marked their surnames in bold:

- Francisco “Pancho” **Villa**
- Francisco Vázquez de **Coronado**
- Diego de **Vargas** Zapata y Luján Ponce de León y Contreras
- Domingo **Jironza** Pétriz de Cruzate

In indexes, I believe it is convention to include names in Last, First order:

- Lincoln, Abraham
- Smith, John

So how do I list these complex Spanish names, when the surnames often aren't at the end?

Comment: Francisco Vázquez de Coronado's last name is "Vázquez de Coronado", not "Coronado". It's like Federico García Lorca, although he is known as Lorca, his first last name is García. And Coronado's actual full name is "Francisco Vázquez de Coronado y Luján", you forgot the last name from his mother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would work the same as english names. for the first name on the list "pancho" is a nickname so it wouldn't go into the last, first order. it would be Villa, Francisco. for longer names like Francisco Vázquez de Coronado, Vázquez de Coronado is his last name. Vázquez de Coronado, Franciso would be the correct name to write it. but for middle names it would be something like Smith, John Doe

hope this helped!